# Kannel - Sending Multipart Messages

Tags: sms, multipart, kannel, sar

I'm hoping someone can shed some light for me on multipart sms's.

Currently the below configuration in kannel works fine for sending a message to the mobile device if the characters are less than 140 characters. What I would like is that if the message contains 140 characters for the message to be delivered to the mobile handset as 1 SMS Message as opposed to 2 or 3 seperate SMS messages.

The guidance I have gotten from our upstream SMPP provider is "sar_msg_ref_num is required to build up the multipart message".

But I have no idea where to start to configure kannel to meet that requirement.

Any tips or pointers to the relevant material will be much appreciated:

```
group = core
admin-port = 13000
smsbox-port = 13001
admin-password = bar
dlr-storage = mysql
log-file = "/var/log/kannel.log"
log-level = 0
box-deny-ip = "*.*.*.*"
box-allow-ip = "x.x.x.x"
sms-combine-concatenated-mo = true

#iTouch SMPP Server

group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = iTouch
interface-version = 34
host = SMPP_PROVIDER
port=9500
smsc-username = SMPP_USRNAME
smsc-password = SMPP_PASSWD
system-type = kannel
transceiver-mode = true
msg-id-type = 0x01
throughput = 15

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = x.x.x.x
sendsms-port = 13013
log-level = 0

group = mysql-connection
id = mydlr
host = localhost
username = kannel
password = **********
database = kannel
max-connections = 1

#DLR DB GROUP
group = dlr-db
id = mydlr
table = msg_pending
field-smsc = smsc
field-timestamp = ts
field-source = source
field-destination = destination
field-service = service
field-url = url
field-mask = mask
field-status = status
field-boxc-id = boxc


group = sendsms-user
        username = linux
        password = t3mp0
            max-messages = 3
            concatenation = 1
            default-sender = 99999999
```

Answer (score 4):

In the following kannel 1.4.3 documentation:@
[Kannel 1.4.3 documentation](http://www.kannel.org/download/1.4.3/userguide-1.4.3/userguide.html) , In SMS-service group, set the following parameter:
concatenation bool
(Long messages can be sent as independent SMS messages with concatenation = false or as concatenated messages with concatenation = true. Concatenated messages are reassembled into one long message by the receiving device.)

e.g:

```
max-messages = 3 
concatenation = true
```

If we omit this parameter, then kannel will simply send the first 160 chars and omit the rest of the message.

Answer (score 1):

First try to use native Kannel concatenation functionality. It's based on UDH and works for most of SMSC.

If this doesn't work you can split messages by your own software and set SAR_* parameters using optional TLV supported by Kannel 1.5.0 (and SVN trunk). Read more about setting optional SMPP TLV in kannel [documentation](http://www.kannel.org/download/kannel-userguide-snapshot/userguide.html#META-DATA)

May be this will also help: [post in kannel maillist](http://www.kannel.org/pipermail/users/2010-March/010369.html)